# Remove items from a List using Lodash

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I have a list where the model is as follows:

Animal model

```
    id
    name
    age
    gender
    city
```

In the `animals[] = [];` list that I have, I need to remove the fields `name, age and gender` and leave `id, and city` in it. How can I do this ?

What I tried:

```
    import { pick,keys } from 'lodash';

    this.animals = pick(this.animals, keys(['name,age,gender']));
```

Error I get

> [ts]
>   Type 'PartialDeep' is not assignable to type 'Animal[]'.
>   Property '[Symbol.unscopables]' is missing in type 'PartialDeep'.

Comment: Didn't get it. Can you show me what you meant? I actually need a animals[] returned.

Comment: change `pick(this.animals, keys(['name,age,gender']));` to `pick(this.animals, keys(['name','age','gender']));`

Comment: @ram12393 but still that doesn't solve my initial problem.

Comment: can you try only `['name','age','gender']` without key??

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash `pick` described as:

> Creates an object composed of the picked object properties.

Your `this.animals` is an Array. This is probably what you are looking for:

```
this.animals.map(animal => pick(animal, keys(['name,age,gender'])));
```